# DataFrame first function ignoreNulls doesn't work

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Reading Spark document first function, it mentioned ignoreNulls would get first non null value.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.{Window, WindowSpec}

object tmp {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark =  SparkSession.builder().master("local") getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._

    val input = Seq(
      (1234,  1, None),
      (1234,  2, Some(1)),

      (5678,  1, Some(11)),
      (5678,  2, Some(22))
    ).toDF("service_id", "counter", "value")

    lazy val window: WindowSpec = Window.partitionBy("service_id").orderBy("counter")
    val firsts = input.withColumn("first_value", first("value", ignoreNulls = true).over(window))
    firsts.orderBy("service_id", "counter").show()
  }
}
```

This returns following output. I want null value in the first row for first_value to be 1.  Am I missing something here

```
+----------+-------+-----+-----------+
|service_id|counter|value|first_value|
+----------+-------+-----+-----------+
|      1234|      1| null|       null|
|      1234|      2|    1|          1|
|      5678|      1|   11|         11|
|      5678|      2|   22|         11|
+----------+-------+-----+-----------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to define the `rangeBetween` option for it to work

```
lazy val window: WindowSpec = Window.partitionBy("service_id").orderBy("counter").rangeBetween(Long.MinValue, Long.MaxValue)
```

Its because if you don't define range in `window` function then incremental range is taken, i.e. for the first row, range is 1 row, for the second row, the range is 2 rows and so on.....  all inside the partitioned window.

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Thanks thats works. Although those seems should have been default value.

Comment: my pleasure @xstack2000, :) and thanks for the upvote and acceptance